# Filter json String using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am working on one small project.
I stuck with one small js issue.
**i have json string like:**

```
var jsObj = {
        "templates": {
            "form0": {
                "ID": "MyAlertNew",
                "isVisible": "true",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "-type": "kButton3",
                        "ID": "myButtonID1",
                        "isVisible": "true",
                        "onClick": "onClickMethod",
                        "paddings": {
                            "left": "0",
                            "right": "0",
                            "top": "3",
                            "bottom": "3",
                            "unit": "%"
                        },
                        "text": "dynamic text in file"
                    },
                    {
                        "-type": "kButton1",
                        "ID": "btnAlign2",
                        "visible": "true",
                        "margins": {
                            "left": "0",
                            "right": "0",
                            "top": "0",
                            "bottom": "0",
                            "unit": "%"
                        }
                    }

                ]
            },
            "form1": {
                "ID": "frmNewPOC1",
                "isVisible": "true",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "-type": "kButton3",
                        "ID": "btnAlign",
                        "isVisible": "true",
                        "onClick": "onClickMethod",
                        "paddings": {
                            "left": "0",
                            "right": "0",
                            "top": "3",
                            "bottom": "3",
                            "unit": "%"
                        },
                        "text": "in diff form"
                    },
                    {
                        "-type": "kButton1",
                        "ID": "btnAlignTest",
                        "visible": "true",
                        "margins": {
                            "left": "0",
                            "right": "0",
                            "top": "0",
                            "bottom": "0",
                            "unit": "%"
                        },
                        "text": "in My Form"
                    }  
                ]
            }
        }
    };
```

**I want to filter it like:**

```
objnew ={
        "MyAlertNew":{
            "isVisible": "true"
        },
        "myButtonID1":{
            "isVisible": "true",
            "onClick": "onClickMethod",
            "paddings": {
                "left": "0",
                "right": "0",
                "top": "3",
                "bottom": "3",
                "unit": "%"
            },
            "text": "dynamic text in file"
        },
        "btnAlign2":{
            "visible": "true",
            "margins": {
                "left": "0",
                "right": "0",
                "top": "0",
                "bottom": "0",
                "unit": "%"
            }
        },
        "frmNewPOC1":{
            "isVisible": "true"
        },
        "btnAlign":{
            "isVisible": "true",
            "onClick": "onClickMethod",
            "paddings": {
                "left": "0",
                "right": "0",
                "top": "3",
                "bottom": "3",
                "unit": "%"
            },
            "text": "in diff form"
        },
        "btnAlignTest":{
            "visible": "true",
            "margins": {
                "left": "0",
                "right": "0",
                "top": "0",
                "bottom": "0",
                "unit": "%"
            },
            "text": "in My Form"
        }
    }
```

so far i have tried with below code but i din get the success.

```
   testObj = jsObj.templates;
        var idObj = [];
        var widgetProp =[];
        var ID ;
        function parseMyObj(testObj){
            for(x in testObj){

                if(typeof testObj[x] == "object"){
                    //widgetProp[]
                    parseMyObj(testObj[x]);
                }
                else if(x=='ID'){
                    ID = testObj[x];  
                    idObj.push(testObj[x]); 

                }
                else{
                    widgetProp.push(x:testObj[x]);
                }
            }
        }
        parseMyObj(testObj);
        console.log(widgetProp);
        console.log(JSON.stringify(idObj));
```

Please help me thanks in advance.

Comment: `parse` not the right word for this function. Parsing usually means you're applying some kind of state machine to transform a plain text into a structure. `transform` would be a better term.

Comment: @Frits van Campen ok i will change it thanks. do you have any solution for my issue?

Answer (score 1):

Well, a simple algorithm (supposing that the key names `ID` and `children` will not change)

1. Create an empty object `N`
2. Iterate on the keys and values of `O`

   - If the value is an object, let `O` be this object and go to 2.
   - If the key is `children`, for each child let `O` be the child and go to 2.
   - If the key is `ID`

     1. Let `name` be the value for this key
     2. Create an empty object `X`.
     3. Copy all the key and values of `O` to `X` except `ID` and `children.`
     4. Assign the built object to the key `name` in your object `N`

Here is a simple implementation (not flexible at all though) of the above algorithm.

```
var createdFormattedObject = function(baseObject, formattedObject) {
  formattedObject = formattedObject || {};

  for(var key in baseObject) {
    if(!baseObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      continue;
    }
    var value = baseObject[key];

    if(key === "ID") {
      formattedObject[value] = {};
      for(var k in baseObject) {
        if(k !== "ID" && k !== "children") {
          formattedObject[value][k] = baseObject[k];
        }
      }
    } else if(key === "children") {
      for(var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
        createdFormattedObject(value[i], formattedObject);
      }
    } else if(value instanceof Object) {
      createdFormattedObject(value, formattedObject);
    }
  }

  return formattedObject;
};
```

Note that the second parameter is only useful for recursing and is not necessary when calling the function.